# Listings package excerpt code lines between with keywords/escape keys?

Tags: listings

Instead of using `firstline=` and `lastline=`, is it possible to include code within a certain, user-defined key? That way, if I wanted to include only one definition of a long file, for example, I would not need to worry about typing above the definition, since that would change the first line.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. There is a script contained in TeXLive, called `listings-ext.sh` to do something like that (take a look at `texdoc listings-ext`). But I personally didn't like the fact that one doesn't get named entries but that they are numbered automatically, so I created a Python script (which should also work on Windows), that does something similar to `listings-ext.sh` but with names, that one isn't publish yet: https://gitlass.de/jonathan/listings-extx.py

Comment: That is very cool, nice work. I was considering making a Python script to simply make new files by scanning the text, extracting text between tags, and generating a new Python file to be used, and using pythontex to automatically run the script when I compile my document. Only downside I can think of is I would lose line numbering capabilities if I wanted to present and excerpt within a large block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listings` provides an experimental feature to include parts of code based on certain begin and end markers (see section 5.7 "Arbitrary linerange markers" of the [`listings` guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)).

The options

```
rangeprefix = <prefix>,
rangesuffix = <suffix>,
linerange   = <startmarker>-<endmarker>
```

would look in the included code for lines

```
... some boring code ...
<prefix><startmarker><suffix>
... interesting code ...
<prefix><endmarker><suffix>
... more boring code ...
```

and include only the interesting parts of the code in the listing (including the start/end markers, unless `includerangemarker=false`). Several marker pairs can be used with `linerange`, all separated by commas. Special characters in the prefix, suffix or markers need to be escaped by `\`.

The disadvantage of this method is that you need to annotate the input code with start and end markers.

Usage example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.hs}
{- begin map -}
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
{- end map -}

{- begin head -}
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x
head []    = error "Prelude.head: empty list"
{- end head -}

{- begin tail -}
tail :: [a] -> [a]
tail (_:xs) = xs
tail []     = error "Prelude.tail: empty list"
{- end tail -}
\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{
    language=Haskell,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
    linerange=8-10
]{\jobname.hs}

\lstinputlisting[
    rangeprefix=\{-\ ,
    rangesuffix=\ -\},
    includerangemarker=false,
    linerange=begin\ head-end\ head
]{\jobname.hs}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I will have to experiment with this. Do you know if there is a character that will hide text from being shown. Similar to `escapechar`, maybe a `hidechar`?  Also, do you know if you can choose to begin numbering at 1 or the number corresponding to the source code?

Comment: @likethevegetable You can set `firstnumber` if you want to start counting from a specific value. I can't come up with a way to hide text right away, maybe you want to ask that as a separate question.